# Late 80's early 90's sci-fi choose your own adventure

Tags: story-identification, choose-your-own-adventure

There was a choose your own adventure book that I read sometime in the late 80's, early 90's. I live in Northern Virginia, if that helps. Anyway, the story was science fiction - possibly a different universe, as none of the characters looked human (other than shape) and the locations didn't look like earth.

I remember a complicated maze that the protagonist had to go through. Also, the protagonist looked *kinda like* a power ranger, but this definitely wasn't power rangers. I believe it was black and white. I remember, maybe space ships - as in at the end of the adventure maybe the protagonist took off?

I've been looking for this book for decades. I believe it was part of a series of choose your own adventure books (as in publisher, the books themselves were not related to each other, just the look/style).

Comment: From your description I THINK it might be the "Be an Interplanetary Spy" series, but without specifics its hard to know which one... many of them had maze challenges and probably many had one of their multiple endings as leaving in a rocket.  The only thin that gives me pause is that they actually were all in the same universe (at least, more or less).  Still, is there anything else you can think of it, or perhaps just google "Interplanetary Spy" and see if you recognize a cover.

Comment: When I say they weren't in the same universe, what I mean is this: As a kid, I'd go to the library and there would be a little set up - basically a shelf of choose your own adventures. This book was there and there were about 50 other choose your own adventure books, none of which were connected. So, there *may* have been other books connected to the book I'm referring to.

I also have a vague memory of a 'companion', maybe? Maybe a robot companion or something *kind of like a cat*, but I'm totally not certain of that.

Comment: I assume you've looked through the entire list online and none of them jump out at you titlewise?

Comment: I've looked through the list on wikipedia and none of them jumped out:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Choose_Your_Own_Adventure_books

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40325/story-book-identification-childrens-books-one-in-space-setting-the-other-in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Was it *[The Planet of Terror](https://www.amazon.ca/Planet-Terror-Choose-Your-Challenge-Gamebook/dp/1564028518)* by Partick Burston and Alastair Graham?

> The reader's quest in The Planet of Terror is to find a spaceship that had to be abandoned just before it crashed. Unfortunately, this planet is chock full of hideous Mutoids, matter-transporter beams, and low-gravity zones. How will the valiant space traveler ever get back to Earth? Every step is a choice; every choice has its risks and rewards. In each of Patrick Burston's Choose-Your-Challenge gamebooks, the reader is assigned a task, then put in control of the direction the story will take. Each page is a new opportunity to alter the course of destiny--at least for this adventure. Along the way, the brave pathfinder will encounter obstreperous obstacles, maddening mazes, mathematical enigmas, and puzzles to perplex even the most clever clue seekers. The way each problem is solved determines which page to turn to next. Often, the intrepid explorer will reach the brink of success, only to be banished to the beginning again, perhaps this time choosing more adroitly among the plethora of permutations for each story.

Comment: I went online to try to find some pictures outside of the cover picture. That *sounds* close. I can't tell if that's it though.