# '80s–'90s science fiction children's book about a gold monkey robot stuck on a planet like a junkyard

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

Okay this one is bugging me. I remember reading this book as a kid.

It was about a robot — pretty sure it also looked like a gold monkey — who was stuck on a planet like a junkyard. I remember that on some pages you had to follow pipelines through like a maze. I believe it had other puzzles. I just remember the artwork being really awesome.

I can't remember the name of it and I'd love to reacquire it for my kiddo.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you actually read this? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I suspect that this is [*The Planet of Terror*](https://archive.org/details/planetofterror0000burs_g3p6), by Patrick Burston and illustrated by Alistair Graham—which is available at via the Internet Archive (although small portions of the page images are missing along the central fold).  Here is the explanation page, showing your golden robot monkey companion, ME2.

[image: Pages 4–5]

Many of the pages were mazes of various types.  Here is a maze in the tubes of Terror City.

[image: Pages 16–17]

And here is the space junkyard puzzle page.

[image: Pages 24–25]

This one has been asked about a number of times before:
[Old series of SciFi adventure puzzle picture books](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/157909/old-series-of-scifi-adventure-puzzle-picture-books)
[Children’s books, one in space setting, the other in a jungle](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40325/children-s-books-one-in-space-setting-the-other-in-a-jungle)
[Late 80's early 90's sci-fi choose your own adventure](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/157454/late-80s-early-90s-sci-fi-choose-your-own-adventure)

Comment: OMG that's it!!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Is this ***[The Planet of Terror](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/41362044-the-planet-of-terror)*** (1985) by Patrick Burston and Alistair Graham...?

> Your mission in this activity book is to find your crashed spaceship and return to Earth, but first you must outwit deadly Tentaclons, ghastly Mutoids, the evil Brain of Terror and other dangers! There are lots of puzzles to solve and many different routes, so you can play again and again.
>
> [image: Front cover of "The Planet of Terror" (1985) by Patrick Burston and Alistair Graham.]

[Someone was looking for this book on Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/21559701-solved-children-s-puzzle-book-with-golden-robot-monkey-puzzles-in-spac) and offered the following description:

> I've been looking for this book for years. It's a kids book, came out in the late 80s or early 90s. **It was a puzzle book and one of the characters was a golden robot monkey. There would be puzzles in space, or there was a city block with stairs to nowhere, backwards signs, things like that. I remember another puzzle was a maze but the layout was like a giant brain. But the main thing I remember was there was a golden robot monkey.** I lost this book as a kid and I've been looking for it for years so hoping someone maybe remembers it.